# 'undefined method' post with Rails and Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

Got stuck with:

```
' undefined method `post' for #<Class:0x000001058c0f68> (NoMethodError)'
```

on testing controller `create` action.

I'm using Rails 4, rpsec, and Factory Girl

Controller:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  @post.user_id = current_user.id

  if @post.save
    flash[:success] = "Yay! Post created!"
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    # flash[:error] = @post.errors.full_messages
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Test:

```
describe '#create' do
  post 'create',  FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:post, user: @user)
  response.should be_successful
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `post` method is accessible inside `it` method block:

```
describe 'create' do
  it 'should be successful' do
    post :create, FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:post, user: @user)
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```

BTW I think you need to test for redirect, not `success` status.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for being off-topic but I just want to give you some advice.

Consider following [best practices](http://betterspecs.org/#expect) and use RSpec's expect syntax instead of should. Read more about why the should syntax is a bad idea here: http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax

This is how I would rewrite your example:

```
describe 'create' do
  it 'responds with 201' do
    post :create, attributes_for(:post, user: @user)
    expect(response.status).to eq(201)
  end
end
```

In the example I'm using FactoryGirl's short syntax method `attributes_for` instead of `FactoryGirl.attributes_for`, it saves a few bytes. Here's how to make the short methods available (in spec/test_helper.rb):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

I'm testing for the status code 201 which Rails will return by default for a successful create action (redirect should be 3xx).This makes the test more specific.

Hope it's any help for writing better specs.

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the fact that `post` should be used inside an `it` statement. I usually test my controllers like this:

```
describe 'POST "create"' do

  let(:user)   { User.new }
  let(:params) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:post, user: user) }
  let(:action) { post :create, params }
  let!(:post)  { Post.new }

  before do
    Post.should_receive(:new).and_return(post)
  end

  context 'on success' do

    before do
      post.should_receive(:save).and_return(true)
    end

    it 'renders success' do
      action
      expect(response).to be_success
    end

    it 'redirects' do
      action
      expect(response).to be_redirected
    end

    it 'sets flash message' do
      action
      expect(flash[:success]).to_not be_empty
    end

  end

  context 'on failure' do

    before do
      post.should_receive(:save).and_return(false)
    end

    it 'renders new' do
      action
      expect(response).to render_template(:new)
    end

  end
end
```